# Input of dynamic size using fgets in C

Tags: c, linux, fgets

I want to have a string(can contain spaces) as input. I want to do dynamic allocation.
Structure of my program is somewhat like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct msgclient
{
    int msglen;
    int msgtype;
    char *cp;
}M1;

int main()
{
    M1 *m;
    m=malloc(sizeof(M1));
    m->msglen=5;
    m->msgtype=6;
    printf("Enter\t");
    fgets(m->cp,50,stdin);  //here
    // m->cp[strlen(m->cp)]='\0';

    printf("\n%d\n%d\n",m->msglen,m->msgtype);
    fputs(m->cp,stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know how to get input. Is there any way that the second argument of fgets be dynamic?

Comment: For "m->cp" you need to allocate memory before you pass the "cp" to the fgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) -instead of [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html)- which reads a dynamically allocated line.

```
typedef struct msgclient {
  ssize_t msglen;
  int msgtype;
  char *cp;
}M1;
```

then in your `main` function

```
M1 *m;
m=malloc(sizeof(M1));
if (!m) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
m->msglen=0;
m->msgtype=6;
m->cp = NULL;
printf("Enter\t");
fflush(stdout);
size_t msgsize = 0;
m->msglen = getline(&msg->cp, &msgsize, stdin);
```

you might consider adding the allocated size of the buffer (i.e. `msgsize`) as an additional field of `struct msgclient`

#### addenda:

Notice that you might perhaps consider using [GNU readline](http://www.gnu.org/software/readline/). It offers edition and completion facilities (when reading from a terminal).

Comment: thanks sir. But I would like to know which is a better function : getline or fgets ?

Comment: Read their appropriate documentation. For your purpose, `getline` is better.

Comment: what int msgtype variable for?