# how to find out if there is a newline or number in c?

Tags: c, char, newline

I have this assignment where I have to read till the "?" char and then check if it is followed by number and newline, or newline and then the number and than again newline. 
I checked the first char after the "?"

if (scanf("%c",c)=='\n') ...;

but that only works if the first one is a newline, and when it isn't and i want to read the number instead, it cuts the first digit ... for example, it doesn´t read 133 but only 33
... how do i do this?

I also tried puting the char back, but that wouldn't work

please help :)

Comment: You might want to start by [reading a `scanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). And also read about e.g. [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc).

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be good.

Comment: Tip: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ungetc

Answer (score 1):

One advantage of `getline` over either `fgets` (or a distant `scanf`) is that `getline` returns the actual number of characters successfully read. This allows a simple check for a `newline` at the end by using the return to `getline`. For example:

```
while (printf ((nchr = getline (&line, &n, stdin)) != -1)
{
    if (line[nchr - 1] = '\n')   /* check whether the last character is newline */
        line[--nchr] = 0;        /* replace the newline with null-termination   */
                                 /* while decrementing nchr to new length       */
```

Comment: `nchr--` should be `--nchr`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html), or better yet, [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22604588/841108)) to read the entire line, then parse the line using [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) or [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26693244/841108))

<sup>Don't forget to carefully read the documentation of every function you are using. Handle the error cases - perhaps using `perror` then `exit` to show a meaningful message. Notice that `scanf` and `sscanf` return the number of scanned items, and know about `%n`, and that `strtol` can set some end pointer.</sup>

Remember that on some OSes (e.g. Linux), the terminal is a [tty](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) and is often line-buffered by the kernel; so nothing is sent to your program until you press the <kbd>return</kbd> key (you could do raw input on a terminal, but that is OS specific; consider also `readline` on Linux).

Answer (score 0):

```
this line: if (scanf("%c",c)=='\n') ...; will NEVER work.  
scanf returns a value that indicates the number of successful parameter conversions. 
suggest: 
// note: 'c' must be defined as int, not char
// for several reasons including:
// 1) getchar returns an int
// 2) on some OSs (dos/windows) '\n' is 2 characters long
// 3) if checking for EOF, EOF is defined as an int
if( '\n' == (c = getchar() ) )
{ // then  found newline
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
    int num;
    scanf("%*[^?]?");//read till the "?"
    while(1==scanf("%d", &num)){
        printf("%d\n", num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/cV4KxW)